# Installing Magento 2.2.4 on windows localhost using xampp

Tags: permissions, command-line, magento2.2.4

I am trying to install Magento 2.2.4 on windows localhost using XAMPP.

My XAMPP is installed I `C:\xampp7.1`

To use command line I using Command prompt in `C:\xampp7.1\php>`

And the following command:

> php C:\xampp7.1\htdocs\Magento2_2_4\bin\magento setup:install
>   --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento224 --db-user=root --db-password=root --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/Magento2_2_4/ --backend-frontname=admin --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin --admin-email=admin@email.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin@123

But it always giving error:
Can't create directory

> C:/xampp7.1/htdocs/Magento2_2_4/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Config/ConfigSourceAggregated/.
>   in [Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated\Proxy]

I have given Magentonto root directory permission 777 using Cygwin

Please guide me in setting proper permissions to Magento's root directory and its ownership on windows localhost

Comment: You can struggle of course with all stuff you'll face with using windows. But the best solution is vagrant or Docker. So if you ask for guide - then my first step of guide for you is - use linux. Magento2 doesn't support windows.

Comment: As which user are you running the php /bin/magento command? I also agree with @StepanFurman - switch over to a real linux environment using vagrant or docker. Not much works very well under windows =(

Comment: As administrator

Comment: @Cyclonecode What's the difference if permissions - 777?

Comment: I think there was some issue when using chmod 777 Magento224 
because I haven't been able to edit or delete any files after this. So I have just deleted whole magento folder and re extracted it. It is now working fine.. I am never ever going to use chmod 777 with cygwin in windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove generated folder and try again.

Comment: This should really be a comment, your answer that is =)

Comment: this worked for me along with setting the permission to magento root, pub and static folder on windows
takeown /F C:\xampp\htdocs\magento223